# Many to many relationship with ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: ado.net, many-to-many

I've created many-to-many relationship with ADO.NET with extra order fields in the middle table.

So I have...

```
Customers
-customer_id
-customer_name

Orders
-order_id

Customers_to_Orders
-customer_id
-order_id
-seq
```

And now I don't really know how to add new orders to customers with specyfing order, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create the order first.

Get the ID back for the order.

Then, create the link from the customer to the order.

Answer (score 0):

you add the order to orders table first, and then add it to customer_to_orders preferably in one transaction.

if you're worried about the seq - it can be either identity or you can calculate "next seq" by querying customers_to_orders before adding new data.